# Как получить список пользователей из Active Directory?

Tags: php

Как получить список пользователей из Active Directory c последующим выводом в ComboBox? В инете нашёл примеры в основном для дэлфи, а мне необходимо php

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно искать на ASP. На сервер 2008 есть замечательный язык Windows Power Shell. Думаю, можно на нем попробовать написать, чтоб возвращало список пользователей, и запускать этот скрипт с PHP с помощью exec.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку LDAP для PHP (она не задействована по умолчанию). [Пример использования](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php).

Comment: и браузер IE для пущей уверенности в результате, если в форточках сидите. Но это, скорее, для авторизации